# IE9 Compatibility Mode Error: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ie-compatibility-mode

I am trying to get the children of a `<tr>` element in a table. I need to get each of the individual `<td>` cells. I cannot use jQuery, only JavaScript for infrastructure reasons. My JavaScript looks like this:

```js
var feeTable = document.getElementById("feeTable");

function gatherRowData() {
  console.log("gathering row data");
  var rows = this.parentNode.children; //This is where it fails.
  var state = rows[0].innerText;
  var county = rows[1].innerText;
  var city = rows[2].innerText;
  console.log("state: " + state);
  document.getElementById("state_code").value = state;
  document.getElementById("county_name").value = county;
  document.getElementById("city_name").value = city;
}

//Loop through Vehicle Fee Changes to find any empty cells in county, city, or start date.
for (var i = 0; row = feeTable.rows[i]; i++) {
  var county = row.cells[1];
  var city = row.cells[2];
  var startDate = row.cells[6];

  if (county.innerText == "") {
    county.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    showError(invalidCells);
  }
  if (city.innerText == "") {
    city.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    showError(invalidCells);
  }
  if (startDate.innerText == "") {
    startDate.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    showError(invalidCells);
  }

  if (document.addEventListener) {
    row.cells[8].addEventListener("click", gatherRowData);
  } else if (document.attachEvent) { //Support for IE
    row.cells[8].attachEvent("onclick", gatherRowData);
  }
}
```

The onClick listeners work just fine, but when I try to get the children of the table row, it gives me the error: `Error message: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined` It works fine in all other browsers, and IE9 without compatibility mode on (it is required to function with compatibility mode). What am I missing that would allow me to get the children of the `tr` element?

Comment: Perhaps try `.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td')` instead of `.parentNode.children`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. It turns out that when you use attachEvent to attach an event listener, the reference to `this` in the JavaScript event handler function doesn't actually reference the object that is being clicked on. It represents the Window object as a whole. I had to use a slightly less elegant solution:

```
row.cells[8].onclick = gatherRowData;
```

This is the only solution that would work for the versions of IE that don't support `addEventListener`. Using this solution, the rest of my code worked fine and `this` referenced the `<td>` element as it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur when the feeTable has null value

```
var feeTable = document.getElementById("feeTable");
```

Try writing values of feeTable in console, and check it has proper value other than null.